# strange behaviour of mongodb 2.1.1 on raspberry pi - can't insert float number

Tags: mongodb, floating-point, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I'm having trouble with my mongodb on my raspberry pi. I'm running version 2.1.1 from https://github.com/RickP/mongopi

The problem is: I can't insert a value of `1.937` on the database. Here is my output from the  `mongo` shell:

```
> db.sensor.drop()
true
```

I clean the collection first, so everything is clean

```
> db.sensor.insert({'sensor_id': 3, 'value': 1.937})
> db.sensor.findOne()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5134fb85e59d6e0efe256a79"),
    "sensor_id" : 3,
    "value" : -2.960244045726579e-47
}
```

As you can see, the value of 1.937 is stored wrong on the database... which is really strange.

if I run the following command:

```
> db.sensor.insert({'sensor_id': 3, 'value': 2})
```

then I get

```
> db.sensor.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5134fb85e59d6e0efe256a79"), "sensor_id" : 3, "value" : -2.960244045726579e-47 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5134fcece59d6e0efe256a7a"), "sensor_id" : 3, "value" : 2 }
```

as you can see, the second entry is good... The trouble is only with the floating value.

why?

thanks

Comment: I just tried the same command on mongolab.com, running also mongod 2.1.1, and my problem is reproducible. I think I'm making a very obvious mistake, because this just can't be... but I don't get it :-)

Answer (score 0):

unable to reproduce it in a local instance of MongoDB 2.1.1

```
MongoDB shell version: 2.1.1
connecting to: test
> db.version()
2.1.1
> db.xx.drop()
false
> db.xx.insert({'sensor_id': 3, 'value': 1.937})
> db.xx.insert({'sensor_id': 3, 'value': 3})
> db.xx.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51586b66cff42dd9c4bc608c"), "sensor_id" : 3, "value" : 1.937 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51586b6ccff42dd9c4bc608d"), "sensor_id" : 3, "value" : 3 }
```

Comment: on the mongo console, try `a = 1.2` and then `a`. I tried on 2 different machines running mongo 2.1.1. The problem is on the mongo console, not on mongo.